# This std::function is similar to

Tags: c++

I was practicing lambdas, and I found this code:

```
auto make_fibo() 
{
  return [](int n) {
    std::function<int(int)> recurse;
    recurse = [&](int n){ 
       return (n<=2)? 1 : recurse(n-1) + recurse(n-2); 
    }; 
    return recurse(n);
  };
}
```

I did not know it was this, exactly, did not know him`std::function<int(int)> recurse;` and after searching and reading this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/

my question is? This std::function is similar to this for example:

```
typedef  int (*FredMemFn)(int i);
```

Thank you and sorry for English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::function` type is a generalization of function pointers. C++ makes a distinction between functions, member functions, and function objects (if you haven't heard of that last one, go look it up! They're super cool!), so a normal function pointer can't point at all the types of things in C++ that you can call like a function. `std::function` is essentially a type that acts like a function pointer that can point at just about anything that you could call like a function. To use `std::function` to point to something with argument types `Arg1, Arg2, ..., ArgN` and return type `Ret`, declare a variable of type

```
std::function<Ret (Arg1, Arg2, ..., ArgN)>
```

Comment: I did not know, but now I think this very well, and a very clean syntax, thanks for your response